# How can I use dynamic variable @counter in my select query as TOP value

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I need a loop in SQL Server 2008 like below:

```
while @counter < (Select Count(Id) from #Requests)
begin
  exec ApplyData(Select TOP 1 Id 
                 from (select TOP @counter Id from #Requests) T
                 order by Id Desc
                )
  set @counter = @counter + 1
end
```

It says the usage of @counter inside the Select query is wrong (syntax error). What is the correct way to use it? How can I fix the syntax error?

Thanks

Comment: either use a CTE with ROW_NUMBER to filter out or make it dynamic

Comment: `SELECT TOP 1 FROM (SELECT TOP @counter....)`?, and then `set @counter = @counter +1`?, what's the point of that?

Comment: lookup sp_executesql for making it dynamic

Comment: From what I see posted I would consider looking closer at the actual process and see if it could modified so you don't need to loop at all.

Answer (score 2):

Use like this

```
select TOP(@counter)
```

Comment: DownVoters care to comment

Comment: I did not downvote but this syntax wont work in sql server

Comment: didn't downvote, but an answer must generally address the whole question. In this case, even if op uses this, his/her code will fail

Comment: @Lamak agree what you say but i just pointed where op goes wrong and this may not require explanation at all

Comment: @JaydipJ but it's not the only part where op goes wrong. There's plenty more in the question

Comment: @GuidoG refer the link for syntax https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189463.aspx

Comment: @JaydipJ I stand corrected it does works. +1 for you